# Animation will not return to starting position:

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I have a animation on a disc.  When touched this disc rotates.  If another button is touch for a different function it hids the disc. whether the animation is finished or not.  After some other functions are complete the disc may become visible again....but it isn't in the starting position but in I believe the position that it was in when it was hidden.

This is how I call the animation-

```
GameObject.Find("disc").GetComponent<coinSpin>().coinSpinNOW()
```

This is how it looks in that function-

```
animation.Play("Take 001");
```

This is what I have tried to get the disc to be in the starting position before being visiblwe again.

```
GameObject.Find("disc").GetComponent<coinSpin>().stopAnim();

public void stopAnim()
{
    animation["Take 001"].time = 0;
    gameObject.SampleAnimation(animation.clip, 0);
    animation.Rewind("Take 001");

}
```

But it isn't working.  You can see I have tried a few different things.  How can I do this??

Comment: Please update your title with your specific problem.. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**animation.clip** you used returns the default animation clip of the animation component. You seem to want to use **Take 001** animation clip. Then you should change the first argument of **SampleAnimation** method like below.

```
gameObject.SampleAnimation(animation["Take 001"].clip, 0);
```

Comment: I have the function set up correctly? Just change it to your code?  and get rid of the others in that function?

Comment: Rest codes look fine. Try changing the argument of SampleAnimation.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it this evening and let you know.

Comment: Dish,  It didn't work.  But not sure if I called it in at the right time.  When should this be called??

Comment: Well, my thinking is changed while I'm reading your question again. Call animation.Stop() when you hide the disc. The animation will be not only stopped but also rewound by this single call. And then call Play() when you show the disc again.

Comment: I tried  animation.stop();  that didn't work either.  I am wondering if it has to do with me using "disc.SetActive(false);" to hide the disc and unhide it.   Also the animation for the disc is on the disc model...should I call this from the main class file and not use the code on the actual disc?

Comment: Dish, I believe I got it working but I used the first line you told me to use when the disc appears again.   No I need to get the disc to not respond to touches while the animation is playing.

Comment: Yes it is working.  Thank you.  Could I just use the "if(animation.Isplaying("Take 001") == false)"  to make the animation not play if it is playing?

Comment: Yes, you can. But it's not necessary to check it's playing.

Comment: Just for clarification Dish,  I needed to do that check so the disc could not be touched while the animation was playing.  Thanks for your help, much appreciated...:)